Will a charge be attracted to current carrying wire,
If we have current carrying wire(infinetly long) at potential 10V(say) in 2D space and a positive charge somewhere at a distance from wire(intially at rest).
Will the charged particle be attracted to wire. Why? I thought E field due to wire is zero outside as it has same no. of positive and negative charge i.e it is electrically neutral.
Ignore B field coz B field genereted due to current has nothing to do with the question. I think.

There will be regions where it is attractive, and regions where it is repulsive. You have specified insufficient information to know what the actual result will be

I didn't specify too much coz i doubted at the very exitence of a force field but now assume any information necessary for a attractive force to exist, why would even such a force exist?

If you read JD Jackson, in chapters 2 and 3, he covered the fact that a conductor, when a test charge is brought near to it, there would be induced charges. These induced charges will attract the test charge. Even if the conductor is supposed to repel the test charge because both are charged with the same sign, there will always be a distance close enough that the induced charges attraction overcomes the overall repelling. This contribution is an important lower bound on the work function of a metal. Your wire is a metal.
